# I can not upload new version of my apps in google play store after upgrading to newer version using same key.jks file as the version before

Tags: android, upload, apk

Please kindly advice about my case. I have existing apps in google play store. presently reach 4th version.
I have the keystore.jks, password and alias. All complete.

Then, I want to increase my version to 5th version using same key.jks, password and alias. generate signed APK as usual. 
Unfortunately, when uploaded to google play store it returns an error like this.

============================

**Upload failed**

You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that expires too soon. You need to sign your APK with a certificate that expires farther into the future. Learn more about signing.
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: D3:0F:62:A6:40:9E:F2:F7:31:A6:EB:2F:FA:35:62:33:C7:E5:75:BA ]
and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: 35:D2:6C:8E:35:27:0F:F4:E4:68:0A:CD:17:BE:C7:84:A5:A9:04:12 ]

**Upload another APK**

Upload failed
You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that expires too soon. You need to sign your APK with a certificate that expires farther into the future. Learn more about signing.
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: D3:0F:62:A6:40:9E:F2:F7:31:A6:EB:2F:FA:35:62:33:C7:E5:75:BA ]
and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: 35:D2:6C:8E:35:27:0F:F4:E4:68:0A:CD:17:BE:C7:84:A5:A9:04:12 ]

## Upload another APK

I wonder why it happened and what caused this to happen because I never changed the key.jks file.

pls kindly advice.
thanks

Comment: your  jks expiry date is in near future. who make that jks put date that close

Comment: how many years gave validity  when create ceritifcate that why your certificate going to expire

Comment: then you need to make another jks file,and change package info and reupload apk with fresh start. old ap

Comment: 25 years @Vadivel

Comment: can google play accepted it? @Divyesh ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately,There is no way to edit / change keystore certificate for a published app, you have to re-publish to do that.before you can change your app package name , version and version code ,For more detail refer http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you validate the jks file with the <...> placeholders replaced with your credentials if you have them, and check the expiration date, just to be sure:

```
keytool -list -v -alias <alias> -keystore <keystore> -storepass <passwd>
```

See discussion at: http://www.unix.com/solaris/235879-keytool-command-check-expiration-dates-certificates.html

---

Now, it seems that you are out of luck (as noted in the comments) and the app needs to be resubmitted with a newly generated certificate.

Comment: Valid from: Sun May 29 01:25:15 ICT 2016 until: Thu May 23 01:25:15 ICT 2041
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  41:23:08:09:8F:C6:80:1A:8C:42:11:7F:1B:D1:EC:B7
         SHA1: D3:0F:62:A6:40:9E:F2:F7:31:A6:EB:2F:FA:35:62:33:C7:E5:75:BA
         SHA256: 76:75:FC:59:B4:20:03:E8:8A:07:CD:AD:A4:3B:73:E7:B7:C2:68:82:71:7E:29:16:2B:65:C7:2E:2F:9E:8E:1D
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
         Version: 3

Comment: until: Thu May 23 01:25:15 ICT 2041 @GiraGira, what do you think?

Comment: This looks fine, but the SHA1 is different to the one reported by Google (I am not sure if they should match), but can you triple check if you really used the same key for version 4 and version 5?

Comment: how to triple check? if i am not mistaken key.jks i used are same from version 1 to version 4.

Comment: Hmm... then I am out of ideas; just resubmit the app then with a new key.

Comment: is it possible or not if android studio has error inside, i mean need to be installed again? because i just update some items.

Comment: Highly unlikely, I never had anything like this happen to me.